# How to modify and get session's variables with Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm working on a form which is rendered in all web site's pages, I need that the server (Django) stops rendering this form on the web pages  if the user closes or completes it. I've been reading about `request.session` but it does not clear the data when, for example, I restart the browser or clean the cache.

Any idea about how to do this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a variable that you can use to display the form. In your views.py something simple like

```
request.session['pending']= true
```

Then in html you put the form within an if statement such as

```
{% if request.session.pending %} 
  <form>
     blah blah
  </form> 
{% endif %}
```

Then back in your views, you set request.session['pending']= false if the form is submitted or exited

Comment: The variable `pending` would be false if go to another site's page (the form is evaluated again). I need that pending keeps its value along the session duration

Comment: how about request.session['pending'] ?